# ASP.NET Core convert http response message to IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to convert a http response message into an IEnumerable, but I get the error:

`JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable 1[MyProject.Models.MyClass]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.`

Here is my code:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<MyClass>> GetAsync()
        {
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(
               HttpMethod.Get,
               "https://xxx/api/123")
            {
                Headers =
                {
                    { HeaderNames.Authorization, "password" },
                }
            };

            var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

            if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                using var contentStream =
                    await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

                Ipads = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
                    <IEnumerable<MyClass>>(contentStream); // HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR HITS
            }

            return MyClasses;
        }
```

Here is the same GET but in Postman working:
[image]

Thanks beforehand!
Best regards Max

Comment: `IEnumerable` is an interface,  why not use its implementation class like `List` ?

Comment: Now that I think of it, it doesnt really matter, List is even better in this case I belive, but I still get the same error here: `Ipads = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync`

Comment: when you change it to `list`, It still show the error like `The JSON value could not be converted to List`??

Comment: Here is the exception: `JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List 1[MyProject.Models.MyClass]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.`

Comment: I tested it in my project, It will not report the error like yours, You need to check the response get from httpclient.

Comment: I cannot find the response body that I am looking for, when I do the same GET with Postman I get the body I want, but I cannot find it in the httpResponseMessage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to await the content from the `HttpResponseMessage` as string.

```
var responseContent = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(responseContent);
```

Comment: It has await: `using var contentStream =  await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();`

Comment: @MaxK123 i mean `ReadAsStringAsync`, just copy my sample.

Comment: It works kinda, I can now see the response body I am looking for in debugging mode, but this error gets thrown: `JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable 1[MyProject.Models.MyClass]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.` Is that because of the class is not matching the response JSON?

Comment: @MaxK123 are you sure your response is List? check `responseContent`  variable with breakpoint

Comment: @MaxK123 you need to change last line of my code to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(responseContent);`

Comment: I am using that line, and JsonConvert with `using Newtonsoft.Json;` right?

Comment: Right, `JsonConvert` is in `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Comment: I see, I still had DesierializeObject<List<MyClass>>, when I do DesierializeObject<MyClass>, it doesnt crash, but everything is null, I get a list of different objects in my http response and I need to put them in some sort of List to use them. Can I do that somehow with this?

Comment: Just add breakpoint on first line of my code and check `responseContent ` value.

Comment: How do I make a list of all the objects inside the results nested inside the response? If you know what I mean, there are some values like date, etc and a resulsts with all the objects I want, can I add them all into a single list?

Comment: try to use `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken` to get nested list or add master entity model to your `MyClass` cless.

Comment: I belive the problem is that the HttpResponseString is very weired looking, it looks like this: ` "{\"count\":430,\"next\":\ ` and so on, with the \ probably ruining the JSON format, any idea?

Comment: with `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken` you can navigate in your props.